# How can I assign a dynamic array to a Variant?

Tags: arrays, delphi, variant, delphi-11-alexandria

I have this code, and when I run it I get an error

> Invalid variant type conversion

in `TConfigDatabase.CreateRoot` when I try to assign the `GItems` to `Root.Data`. What can be wrong here?

```
unit OwnConfig;

interface

const
  gidRoot = 0;

type
  PConfigItem = ^TConfigItem;
  TConfigItem = record
    ID: Cardinal;
    Desc: String;
    Data: Variant;
  end;
  TConfigGroup = array of TConfigItem;

  TConfigDatabase = record
  public
    Root: TConfigItem;
    procedure CreateRoot;
    function  SetGroup(Parent: PConfigItem; TheID: Cardinal; Desc: String = ''): PConfigItem;
  end;

implementation

uses System.Variants;

procedure TConfigDatabase.CreateRoot;
var GItems: TConfigGroup;
    VarArray: Variant;
begin
  SetLength(GItems, 0);
  Root.ID:= gidRoot;
  Root.Desc:= '*ROOT*';
  Root.Data:= GItems;       // get "Invalid variant type conversion" exception
end;

function TConfigDatabase.SetGroup(Parent: PConfigItem; TheID: Cardinal; Desc: String = ''): PConfigItem;
var L, I: Integer;
    PItems, GItems: TConfigGroup;
begin
  PItems:= TConfigGroup(Parent.Data);
  L:= Length(PItems);
  SetLength(PItems, L+1);
  PItems[L].ID:= TheID;
  PItems[L].Desc:= Desc;
  SetLength(GItems, 0);
  PItems[L].Data:= GItems;
  Parent.Data:= PItems;
  Result:= @TConfigGroup(Parent.Data)[L];
end;

end.
```

Comment: Consult [the documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Variant_Types_(Delphi)#Variant_Arrays). Moreover, `Variant` cannot carry any `Record`.

Comment: @AmigoJack but my array is nost static, is dynamic `TConfigGroup = array of TConfigItem;`. And I don't assign records to the Variant... That `Data` Variant variable will carry simple types or that dynamic array.

Comment: Read all the text: "_Variants can hold values of any type except records..._" and your `TConfigGroup` is an `Array of Record`. Do you think logic can be tricked this easy? If `Record` is not directly allowed, then just make it an `Array`? Not sure why you need a dynamic array at all when `VarArrayCreate()` is as dynamic as using `SetLength()` anyway.

Comment: @AmigoJack you need to read the documentation more carefully yourself: "*You can define custom Variants that extend the Variant type to hold arbitrary values. For example, you can define a Variant string type that allows indexing or that holds a particular class reference, **record type**, or static array... The elements of a variant array can be of **any type** allowed in variants except ShortString and AnsiString...*"

Comment: Configuring the variant as a dynamic array and assigning each item individually doesn't suit you ?. 

    `Root.Data := VarArrayCreate(0, Length(GItems) - 1, varVariant);
    for i := 0 to Length(GItems) - 1 do Root.Data[i] := GItems[i];`

It does what you asked: to assign a dynamic array to a variant. The only problem is that you have to assign it item by item.